# How can I force user and password prompt when pushing to my git repository?

Tags: git, github

I recently updated my local Git installation to `1.8.1` from `1.8.0.1`.

I'm noticing that, when I work on GitHub, it doesn't prompt me for username and password on push anymore.

This troubles me, as I see having to type user and password every time as a good security measure. (what if someone else uses my computer?)

I checked the following:

- `1.8.0.1` on another computer still asks for username and password.
- my account on github still enforces private/security controls.
- I am using https remote references, rather than ssh.
- For good measure, I checked in my `~/.ssh` fonder. Nothing wrong there.
- I'm **not** storing the login details in `~/.gitconfig` or individual `<proj>/.git/config` files.
- I'm also **not** storing anything github-related in `~/.netrc`.
- I created a new dummy archive: still doesn't prompt me for login.

I couldn't find anything in the git [release notes archive](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/Documentation/RelNotes).

Does anyone know if this is a new git behaviour? How do I restore the prompt?

Comment: Do you have a `%HOME%\_netrc` file with your credential in it? (as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11021803/need-github-without-username-and-password/11022181#11022181) Or do you have some kind of credential caching activated? (as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191985/git-http-securely-remember-credentials/12938677#12938677) Or are you working with GitHub for Windows?

Comment: Thanks. I'm working on OS X. I do have a `~/.netrc` file, but there isn't anything github related in there (forgot to mention that, adding it now). With `git config -l` I now see I have a `credential.helper=osxkeychain` option. Thanks, I'll read the manpages. Could you expand your comment as an answer?

Comment: Comment expanded as an answer, with links to references.

Comment: I used `git config --global --unset credential.helper` and `git config --system --unset credential.helper` and it brought back the login prompt.

Comment: Note that "bring back the prompt" doesn't solve "what if someone else uses my computer?" worry — you also want to find & delete whereever the credential helper stored passwords (whether it's files or OS keychain)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> With `git config -l`, I now see I have a `credential.helper=osxkeychain` option

That means the **[credential helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191985/git-http-securely-remember-credentials/12938677#12938677)** (initially introduced in 1.7.10) is now in effect, and will cache automatically the password for accessing a remote repository over HTTP.
(as in "[GIT: Any way to set default login credentials?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13870717/6309)")

You can disable that option entirely, or [only for a single repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13203623/6309).

Comment: thanks. it took me a while because for some reason the option was in the `--system` config file, rather than in the `--global` one. Still wondering how that got switched on.

Comment: Had you installed GitExtensions or any other client, which switched it on? I dont remember switching it on until I installed GitExtensions.

Comment: Apparently, this might be the cause. The credential cache daemon. Not sure if the same is the cause on Windows though. https://stackoverflow.com/a/15382950/15789

Comment: @RuntimeException on Windows, by default, the credential helper is the Microsoft Credential Manager (so, no daemon): https://stackoverflow.com/a/42152514/6309

Comment: Thanks, this sent me on the right path. I launched the keychain access tool in OS X and just deleted all the github stuff there... Solved the problem.

Answer (score 188):

Add a -v flag with your git command . e.g.
`git pull -v`

> v stands for verify .

Comment: @joao I saw one of my colleague using this command , and I promptly remembered it . Never saw this anywhere documented as well . It looks more like --verbose flag , not sure why it works :)

Comment: yes . It caught my attention as well , it looks like verbose , or version ... But actally it stands for `verify` . Git has strange nomenclatures.

Comment: Perfect!  Forces re-authentication as advertised.

Comment: git version 1.7.1 man pages show that `-v` stands for verbose for `git-pull` and `git-fetch`

Comment: Did absolutely nothing for me. Did not prompt for anything. Just pushed.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Straight to the point and it works.

Comment: This is the real answer, imho--with the -v option I re-entered my credentials and am all set.  The reason I needed to reverify is because my corporate password had changed.

Answer (score 115):

This is most likely because you have multiple accounts, like one private, one for work with GitHub.

**SOLUTION
On Windows**, go to Start > Credential Manager > Windows Credentials and remove GitHub creds, then try pulling or pushing again and you will be prompted to relogin into GitHub

**SOLUTION
OnMac**, issue following on terminal:

```
git remote set-url origin https://username@github.com/username/repo-name.git
```

by replacing 'username' with your GitHub username in both places and providing your GitHub repo name.

or add the password/token as well

```
git remote set-url origin https://username:<pass/token>@github.com/username/repo-name.git
```

Answer (score 20):

None of those worked for me. I was trying to clone a directory from a private git server and entered my credentials false and then it wouldn't let me try different credentials on subsequent tries, it just errored out immediately with an authentication error.

What did work was specifying the user name (`mike-wise`)in the url like this:

```
   git clone https://mike-wise@collab.somewhere.net/someuser/somerepo.git
```

Comment: This made the difference for me (I'm on a managed machine that will not allow access to the credentials manager)

Comment: My Power Shell got stucked and this worked for me. Just got to type password on the Windows Credential Helper Box. :)

Comment: Very simple and elegant solution for credentials prompt on Windows.

Answer (score 5):

Since the question was labeled with `Github`, adding another remote like `https_origin` and add the `https` connection can force you always to enter the password:

```
git remote add https_origin https://github.com/.../...
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. I can add the https remote, but it still says 'permisson denied to <myusername>' without prompting me.

Answer (score 3):

Addition to third answer:
If you're using non-english Windows, you can find "Credentials Manager" through "Control panel" > "User Accounts" > "Credentials Manager"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get around the dumb github restriction is making an api token under developer in your profile settings. Then you can change your repo url to be @url

Answer (score 0):

deleting these lines in ~/.gitconfig save me :

````
    extraheader = Authorization: Bearer xxx
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://user:token@github.com/user/repo.git
[alias]
    credential-manager = credential-manager-core
[credential]
    helper = osxkeychain```
````