# How to change user for git repository

Tags: git, github

I have set my global github user settings in my computer.

- user.name "myusername"
- user.email "myemail"

I have second github account with a different name "myusername2". I cloned a repository from "myusername2" account to my computer. But global user settings are "myusername". So I set the username and email using command:

```
git config user.name "myusername2"
git config user.email"myemail2"
```

But when I push commits, the authentication error occured. I think this is for password not authenticated. So how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you using SSH or HTTPS?

Comment: `user.name` and `user.email` are *not* used for authentication. They are only used to write name and email address in your commits.

Comment: @mousetail I am using https.

Comment: @j6t I think so, but what is the solution.

Comment: Can you check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18948007/6577998) and see if it's related to `osxkeychain` credential helper and the `credential.helper`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If an authentication error occurs when pushing with an HTTPS URL, this is because the cached credentials stored by the credential helper (check what `git config credential.helper` returns) are wrong.

To force said credential helper to select the right account, I would add the username in the HTTPS url:

```
cd /path/to/local/repo
git remote set-url origin https://username2@github.com/<username2>/repo
```