# How can I authenticate to our TFS server in my Git for Windows client?

Tags: git, ssl, tfs

We have a TFS 2017 server setup on our corporate domain. I want to use the Git for Windows CMD line to push and pull code from a repo on that TFS server.

I have added the neccessary certs to my local store in order to pass the SSL hurdle, but now when I try and clone the remote repo down into **either my domain joined workstation OR my non-domain laptop**, I get the following error:

```
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://TFSServer/Collection/ABC/_git/Alarm/
```

Why doesn't Git prompt me for my credentials?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you don't have a **[credential helper](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials)** which might have cached the wrong credentials.

Check `git config -l` for any `credential.helper` line.

With recent [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases), you would be using the [Microsoft Git Credential Manager](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows), linked to the [Credential Manager in Windows](https://blog.malwarebytes.com/101/2016/01/the-windows-vaults/)

Answer (score 1):

First suggest you [Use  Git Credential Managers to Authenticate to Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/set-up-credential-managers)

When you connect to a TFS Git repository from your Git client for the first time, the credential manager will prompt for your credentials.

Another option is using [SSH key authentication](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate)

> Connect to your Git repos through SSH when you can't use the
>   recommended **Git Credential Managers** or **Personal Access Tokens** to
>   securely connect using HTTPS authentication.