# Is there a way to remove GitHub passwords cached by Visual Studio Code in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I tried to push / pull code from a private repository which I have access to and instead I get the error below:

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/path-togit.git/'
```

I have searched and tried all solutions provided on different platforms, but none works. For example, deleting the *vscodegithub* entry in passwords and keys, but still it doesn’t work.

I tried the following but they do not work in my case:

- *[Error pushing to Git remote with HTTP #1138](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/1138)*
- *[Changing the Git user inside Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42318673/changing-the-git-user-inside-visual-studio-code/42319503)*
- *[How can I remove a GitHub password from Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48413031/how-to-remove-github-password-from-vscode)*

I have seen that people reporting these as successful are Windows and Mac users. Is there a solution that works for Ubuntu?

P.S.: I can successfully push/pull using the normal terminal. My problem is with the Visual Studio Code terminal and my operating system is **[Ubuntu 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa))** (Focal Fossa).

Comment: What is your `git config credential.helper`?

Comment: @VonC initially running that command did not return a response then somewhere along trying solutions I changed the cache timeout to 1 second so now when I run `git config credential.helper`  i get `cache --timeout=1`

Comment: What is your `git version`? And does the remote URL exist? (if you type that exact URL, do you get to your provaye repository?)

Comment: @VonC git version `git version 2.31.1` and yes remote URL exists . As mentioned in the question I can pull or push using the normal terminal . But I cant do so using the terminal in vs code . Vs code must  have cached the wrong password when I switched repos sometime and I want it to forget those credentials so I can enter new ones

Comment: OK. VSCode should be using the same credential helper than command-line though. I would install GCM-core (https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core/#linux) and see if that caching works better with VSCode.

Comment: This is a super [FAQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FAQ) (because it affects so many). A candidate for the canonical question is *[fatal: Authentication failed for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69979522/)* (despite the unspecific title).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to solve this with help by installing GCM-core (https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core/#linux)