# Why do I have problems with loging in to Overleaf via git

Tags: git

I want to use the connection between git and overleaf (on Windows 10 with git bash). One time it worked, but now I get always errors.

```
git clone https://git.overleaf.com/number
Cloning into 'number'...
remote: Please sign in using your email address and Overleaf password.
remote:
remote: *Note*: if you sign in to Overleaf using another provider, such
remote: as Google or Twitter, you need to set a password on your Overleaf
remote: account first. Please see https://www.overleaf.com/blog/195 for
remote: more information.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://git.overleaf.com/number/'
```

I set username and password via:

```
git config --global user.name "mail@domain.com"
git config --global user.email "mail@domain.com"
git config --global user.password "**********"
```

It worked once some days ago. There I Overleaf asked me for password and name. But this has changed now. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: May you check their documentation?

Comment: when you mean this: https://www.overleaf.com/blog/195 , I already tried all mentioned things there. Every where I'm looking for, it says save your user name and stuff via git config and as you can see, I already did it.

Comment: Maybe see also [macos - How do I update the password for Git? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20195304/how-do-i-update-the-password-for-git). That having said in my case the issue is I type `MAIL@domain.com` instead of `mail@domain.com` (which the web interface accept, but git reject). Always go to https://www.overleaf.com/user/settings to check what the proper capitalization of the email is.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To store username and password for Overleaf, add the following to your `.gitconfig`:

```
[credential "https://git.overleaf.com"]
    username = your@email
    helper = store
```

Comment: Note: the `.gitconfig` should be in your home directory

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

While setting email and password using `git config` did not work, what did work was:

- forcing a user and password prompt ([Git: force user and password prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643308/git-force-user-and-password-prompt)) by disabling the `credential.helper` ([How do I disable git's credential helper for a single repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198143/how-do-i-disable-gits-credential-helper-for-a-single-repository/13203623#13203623))

So I ran `git config --global credential.helper`. 
The next time I ran `git clone`, `git push`, or `git pull` with the Overleaf repository, a prompt appears asking for my overleaf username and password. Correctly entering the credentials there worked.

Answer (score 2):

Someone may prefer configuration from the command line. The equivalent way to @pavel is to run the following commands

```sh
git config --global credential.https://git.overleaf.com.username your@email
git config --global credential.https://git.overleaf.com.helper store
```

This will result in the config `~/.gitconfig` globally.

Alternatively, one can specify different configurations for different projects by replacing `--global` with `--local`.